# Java and C#, how close are they?

Tags: c#, java, comparison

I've been using C/C++ and Python, but I now I see that a lot of new programming books use Java or C# as examples.

I don't think I'll use Java or C# for the time being, but I guess I have to study one of the languages (or both of them) in order to read/understand the books.

- How similar Java and C#? If I learn Java, is learning C# almost free? Or vice versa?
- If I have to choose only one of the two languages, which would be better? Which has wider coverage in terms of programming language?

Comment: Here's a pretty good break-down of the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610199/the-art-of-programming-java-vs-c

Comment: This question was good until you asked which one is better.

Comment: They're like the suburbs of programming languages basically. Crowded, and there's no fun to be had.

Comment: ...except he explained right after saying 'better' that what he really meant by that was wider coverage, that is something that is measurable, not opinion based (ie; should I take the toll expressway or the freeway, which would be better? which has more space in terms of lanes.)  the number of lanes or total width are subject to opinion??

Comment: Java/C# have more in common than C/C++.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are asking several questions at once. Let me address them separately:

---

> How similar Java and C#?

Both C# and Java drew from C/C++ (and Objective C, and others) to define their syntax. And both of them are compiled to an intermediate language.

This common origin makes the languages *look* similar in many levels, to the point that code in either language can be confused with the other by beginners; and also makes the runtime environment somewhat comparable. However, there are substantial differences in both design principles and how each language evolved that make working with each quite different; here are the most prominent ones:

On the syntax level, Java was influenced by Smalltalk, while C# tried to stay closer to C/C++ (eg: compare Java's `extends` and `implements` with C#'s `:` notation) and took a *vague* inspiration from VB on those concepts that weren't mappable to C/C++ (example: property syntax).

On the features level, C# 1 was definitely close to Java. Among the few differences they had, I'd highlight C#'s support for "unsafe" code (including pointers) and for delegates; and Java's controversial `throws`. This makes sense, since one of the goals of C# was to become an alternative to Java.

Many language features differ heavily on implementation details. For example, enums are very C'ish on C#, but are full objects in Java; or generics are implemented on the IL-level in C#, but in Java are dealt with via type erasure (neither is really close to C++'s templates besides syntax).

On the API level, they are worlds apart. C# relies on the .Net Framework, which was built on Microsoft's experience with the Visual Studio family of products (and thus is significantly Windows-oriented), while Java's Class Library was built, IIRC, from scratch, and heavily evolved over time (on these Swing days, does anyone remember AWT? I do).

Finally, it's worth mentioning that each of the languages has its own idioms, and its own community of supporters behind it.

---

> If I learn Java, is learning C# almost
> free? Or vice versa?

Neither. The key similarity is the basic syntax (semicolons, curly braces, array indexing, case-sensitiveness, etc), and you already have that from C/C++.

---

> If I have to choose only one of the two languages, which would be better?

Short answer: flip a coin.
Long answer: it depends on your coding style and on what aspects of the language you value most. My best advise is to start by trying to learn both, until you feel that one of the languages pulls you more strongly than the other.

Alternatively, you can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp.

---

> Which has wider coverage in terms of programming language?

If you mean language built-in features, I'd say C# wins for a narrow margin. Most of the features that C# has and Java lacks are syntax sugar (although they together make a significant difference on the learning curve and on the way the language is used). I value really high C#'s operator overload and extension methods. Also, LINQ is quite an interesting concept, but it is essentially a declarative syntax for loops.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `the similarities end there` -> goes on to identify `3` differences. In all seriousness.... they really are extremely similar. Imo, a newbie of C# or Java could be forgiven for reading half a C# program anad not being sure if it was Java or C#. Hell, I work on both for a living, and when I first started, the only obvious difference was the coding style conventions (i.e. curly braces below method definition in C#)

Comment: @mmcrae: I agree this is a terrible answer, wonder how it got upvotes, I'd call those two languages also very similar (at least on the main parts). here this topic is treated better: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836794.aspx#tchwhatssimilarbetweencjava

Answer (score 3):

The libraries are very different, and the approach to documentation is very different. I find the C# approach to easier.

To illustrate what I mean, in either language some object that you want to deal with may be implemented by inheriting from "object" to "generic object" to "specific object." In Java, if you want to find out about a property of the "generic object" you have to go to the doc for that, whereas in C# documentation, all the properties are listed for the "specific object."

At least that's the way it seemed to me back a few years ago when I did some Java.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want a brutally subjective answer.

I have just finished a degree in Computer Science in England, I chose a university that taught C# as opposed to Java.........reason being, so I could easily walk straight into a highly paid job as a software developer with a company that simply only wants people who know the "new" technologies.

These are companies such as Investment Banks, tech startups, IT Consulting firms.

#### So if you want to pick one to learn......

Think about the end goal.....if it's cash and modern knowledge...follow C#.

....and if it's anything else, follow C#

P.S. Java is terrible - I had to say it.

Comment: @ Goober Just as a matter of interest, which uni teaches c# over java? I went to City University London and almost all programming was done in Java ( which annoyed me a bit actually).

Comment: `Java is terrible` - everyone thinks the first/only language they learn is the best. and @EShindler - C# / .NET is indeed much less common in uni, and I was surprised to find that some universities in U.S. use .NET. Northern Illinois University for example

Comment: Downvoted. This is Stack Overflow, not Reddit. Adding a "subjective" disclaimer doesn't mean you could add this as an answer. Answers on Stack Overflow should be as objective as possible. For example, there is something called the TIOBE Index that should be there for 20+ years and available at the time this answer was added in 2010. In 2009 and 2010, Java ranked 1st and C# wasn't even top 5. Don't confuse C with C# as they are different. Just a few days ago in 2024, TIOBE Index for Jan 2024 was released and Java is still ranked higher than C#.

Comment: And for those who want to learn programming for getting a "highly paid job", you probably want to choose what to learn first, then the best frameworks, libraries and programming language for it. For example, if you think AI-related jobs generate higher salary than anything else, then you would look for the AI or ML developer roadmap and learn whatever language that is the most popular for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Not a 1:1 mapping since C# 1.0.  C# has added lots of stuff (LINQ, closures,etc.) that have no analog in Java.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Finally... :)

Comment: @BlueRaja: You mean Java 7 *will have* closures when it is finally released, which apparently will not be for the better part of a year.

Comment: I predict lots of security holes.